# Error 403: Project blocked; abuse detected., accessNotConfigured

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a golang program running on my local laptop. I had a previous Google Cloud account that I used to upload images to a bucket (using gcloud local context). It worked.

I created another company branded Google Cloud account and linked our company card to it.

Ever since then I get the error in the title.

I contacted support and got this:

Hi,

Unfortunately we are not able to identify any abuse related actions taken on your project. To resolve this issue, please reach out to the Google Cloud Platform community support.

Sincerely,
Google Cloud Platform/API Trust & Safety Team

Do you guys have any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was going to ask if you had "reach[ed] out to the Google Cloud Platform community support", but then I checked and it appears they are directing  you here.  Have you also posted on the Google Groups?

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the tip. Is there any reason my question would be sitting at -1 right now?

Comment: OK, so it turns out that the Google Group has been archived and they redirect people here.

Comment: I didn't vote either way, but I suspect your down vote was the result of someone A) feeling that you didn't provide enough detail and/or B) Not realizing that Google directed you here. That's actually 1/2 the reason for my previous comment--to let other users know that Google directed you here. Since that person didn't comment, I can't say what his/her reason was. Also, I don't know anything about Google Cloud Storage, so I can't help you with that either. Sorry on both counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the JWT json file being used by my project for authentication was out-of-date.

I had to re-download a new JWT json file from the cloud console and put it in the root of my project folder.